# RFC 2821 - how does client know when to send first command?

Tags: smtp, rfc

From RFC 2821:

D.2 Aborted SMTP Transaction Scenario

```
  S: 220 foo.com Simple Mail Transfer Service Ready
  C: EHLO bar.com
  S: 250-foo.com greets bar.com
  S: 250-8BITMIME
  S: 250-SIZE
  S: 250-DSN
  S: 250 HELP
  C: MAIL FROM:<Smith@bar.com>
  S: 250 OK
  C: RCPT TO:<Jones@foo.com>
  S: 250 OK
  C: RCPT TO:<Green@foo.com>
  S: 550 No such user here
  C: RSET
  S: 250 OK
  C: QUIT
  S: 221 foo.com Service closing transmission channel
```

My understanding is that

```
  S: 250-8BITMIME
  S: 250-SIZE
  S: 250-DSN
  S: 250 HELP
```

is a list of extensions supported by server.
In given example, after receiving this list, client sends the first command EHLO.
But how does it know that there will be no further items in this list? There is no command from server like "LISTING_EXTENSIONS_DONE".
So e.g. if server would only has 8BITTIME extension, how would client know that it's the only one and it shouldn't wait for other extensions to be sent by server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reply to SMTP `EHLO` command contains lines staring with
**`250-...`**  - *more reply lines to follow*
**`250 ...`**  - *the final reply line*

[RFC-2821/4.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.1.1.1)

> **4.1.1.1  Extended HELLO (EHLO) or HELLO (HELO)**
> ...
> Normally, the response to EHLO will be a multiline reply.  Each line
> of the response contains a keyword and, optionally, one or more
> parameters.  Following the normal syntax for multiline replies, these
> keyworks follow the code (250) and a hyphen for all but the last
> line, and the code and a space for the last line.